# new line for tooltip fetching values from the database

Tags: tooltip

```
$price = mysql_result($result, $num, "drinks_shot"); $price2 = mysql_result($result, $num, "drinks_bottle");

$append = $clean_name.'<br> Per shot: Php'.$price.'<br> Per bottle: Php'.$price2.'.00'; $description = mysql_result($result, $num, "drinks_image"); echo "<td class='label'><img src='". mysql_result($result, $num, 'drinks_image')."' onclick='addtocart(". mysql_result($result, $num, 'drinks_id').")'  class='masterTooltip' title= '".$append."'<br>";
```

if only i could make it display like

```
hennessy
price1
price2
```

i found similar posts regarding my problem but none of them are really working. Please help. :(

Comment: Is "display like hennessy" akin to "walk like an Egyptian"?

Comment: err.. Hennessy's the name of the drink.

Answer (score 0):

You want linebreaks inside a `title=""` tooltip? Instead of using `<br>`, use `\n` and make sure it's inside double (`"`) quotes and not single quotes. Like so:

```
$append = $clean_name . "\n Per shot: Php" . $price . "\n ...";
```